# Metal LAF JScrollPane rendering bug?

Tags: java, swing

Having played around with the JScrollPane class for a couple of days, I've come across a very strange rendering problem regarding the horizontal JScrollBar compnent. When using these components within the default swing "Metal" look-and-feel, the center gripper pattern of the horizontal scrollbar appears to render incorrectly at specific content/viewport dimensions.

The code below opens a simple JFrame window with an embedded JScrollPane component, which appears to exhibit strange rendering behaviour **as the horizontal scrollbar is dragged towards its rightmost extemity**. As the rendering of the horizontal scrollbar gripper appears to be dependent upon the size of the content/viewport, this code opens the parent JFrame with an explicit dimension of 1402x800. Varying dimensions appear to have the same effect, including a maximized window at a 1440x900 resolution, and the problem tends to present itself more readily in a non-composited desktop environment (i.e. Windows XP or Vista/7 running a basic/classic theme).

```
public class Main
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  ScrollbarTest application = new ScrollbarTest();
  application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }
}

public class ScrollbarTest extends JFrame
{

 public ScrollbarTest()
 {
  super("Scrollbar Test");
  Container container = getContentPane();

  JScrollPane scrollPane =
    new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

  JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
  contentPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(8000, 8000));

  scrollPane.getViewport().add(contentPanel);
  container.add(scrollPane);

  setSize(1402,800);
  setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

As I am prohibited from uploading images directly to this forum, I have placed an image [here](http://taliadon.mypressonline.com/) depicting the anomaly that I'm currently experiencing. As you can see, the center gripper feature is not rendered correctly as I drag the horizontal scrollbar toward its right extremity.  Please note that this does not appear to happen at all window sizes, but the initial JFrame dimension of 1402x800 certainly does the trick on my system. To be perfectly honest, this problem was not apparent until I moved from a 1280x800 to 1440x900 screen.

Any comments regarding the reproducibility and/or cause of this anomaly would be gratefully received.

Best regards, Lee.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: I do apologise Andrew, but I'm not entirely sure I understand your point.  I have attempted to keep my description as concise as possible – we are physicists; not programmers - and the above code represents my program verbatim.  If I have missed something obvious, please feel free to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for taking the time to read this post. As we are not professional programmers, we had to seek advice in order to ensure that we were using the java API correctly.
We asked the guys at Sun to take a look at our problem, and this does appear to be a bug with the swing "Metal" look-and-feel. Please see below for the relevant correspondence.

> Dear Java Developer,
>
> Thank you for reporting this issue.
>
> We have determined that this report is
> a new bug and entered the bug into our
> internal bug tracking system under Bug
> Id: 7017935.
>
> You can monitor this bug on the Java
> Bug Database at
> https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7017935.
>
> It may take a day or two before your
> bug shows up in this external
> database.  If you are a member of the
> Sun Developer Network (SDN), there are
> two additional options once the bug is
> visible.
>
> 1. Voting for the bug    Click http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/addVote.do?bug_id=7017935.
> 2. Adding the report to your Bug Watch list.    You will receive an email
>    notification when this bug is updated.
>    Click
>    "http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/addBugWatch.do?bug_id=7017935".
>
> The Sun Developer Network
> (http://developers.sun.com) is a free
> service that Sun offers.  To join,
> visit
> "https://softwarereg.sun.com/registration/developer/en_US/new_user".
>
> Regards, Java Developer Support

Best regards, Lee.